# jQuery not defined when using IIFE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to implement a Livesearch list onto a page where it takes an array and its objects and by using the search box, will filter matches and only show match of the search term,

The issue I'm having is that when looping through the array items using a forEach and trying to append the results to the DOM,

> jQuery is Not defined

Essentially the code should grab the array, loop through the array, grab the building names and append each to the `.list` DIV as `h4` items.

```js
//testItemsArray
//array will contain objects used in the mockup for a livesearch function on the map pages.

var testItemsArray = [{
  id: '1',
  building: 'building1'
}, {
  id: '2',
  building: 'building2'
}, {
  id: '3',
  building: 'building3'
}, {
  id: '4',
  building: 'building4'
}, {
  id: '5',
  building: 'building5'
}];

(function($) {
  $search = $('#searchbox'); // This is used for the filter input field

  var buildingList = '',
    buildingh4 = '';
    
  testItemsArray.forEach(function(buildings) {
    buildingh4 = "<h4>" + buildings.building + "</h4>";
    buildingList += buildingh4
    $('.list').html(buildingList);
  });
}(jQuery));
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="./js/list.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Main Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" id="search">
    <header class="header">
      <h1>University Of Lincoln Map Search</h1>
      <h2></h2>
    </header>
    <div class="logo">
      <p>This page is to be used for the locating of campus buildings and rooms</p>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <div class="list">
        ********THIS IS WHERE I WANT ALL ITEMS TO DISPLAY** *****
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="key">
      <div class="key-bg"></div>
      <div class="key-text"><span><h2>Find the room you are looking for</h2></span></div>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <p>map</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Firstly you need to put the reference to jquery.js *before* your code in list.js. Secondly, use a document.ready event handler, not an IIFE, or at least place a document.ready inside the IIFE if you want to work with the DOM. Your current code is being executed *before* the elements have been created in the DOM.

Comment: put jquery before list.js, `jQuery is Not defined` is clear error you can understand.

Comment: Also as an aside, you should look in to the correct way of formatting and commenting code. The double spacing is unnecessary, and a lot of your comments are redundant. I've fixed these issues in the edit.

Answer (score 1):

You should place this line of code before closing the body tag. Instead of using IIFE, use `document.ready`

In your code, you put your `list.js` before `jquery.min.js`, that's why you get `jQuery` is `undefined` error.

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/list.js"></script>
</body>
```

```js
var testItemsArray = [{
  id: '1',
  building: 'building1'
}, {
  id: '2',
  building: 'building2'
}, {
  id: '3',
  building: 'building3'
}, {
  id: '4',
  building: 'building4'
}, {
  id: '5',
  building: 'building5'
}];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $search = $('#searchbox'); // This is used for the filter input field

  var buildingList = '',
    buildingh4 = '';
    
  testItemsArray.forEach(function(buildings) {
    buildingh4 = "<h4>" + buildings.building + "</h4>";
    buildingList += buildingh4
    $('.list').html(buildingList);
  });
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
 
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Main Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" id="search">
    <header class="header">
      <h1>University Of Lincoln Map Search</h1>
      <h2></h2>
    </header>
    <div class="logo">
      <p>This page is to be used for the locating of campus buildings and rooms</p>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <div class="list">
        ********THIS IS WHERE I WANT ALL ITEMS TO DISPLAY** *****
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="key">
      <div class="key-bg"></div>
      <div class="key-text"><span><h2>Find the room you are looking for</h2></span></div>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <p>map</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="./js/list.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your js reference that is
`<!-- listJS cdn link-->
<script src="./js/list.js"></script>`

After Jquery library reference that is below 
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score -1):

You should have a reference to your Jquery library.

```
      // IIFE - Immediately Invoked Function Expression
  (function($, window, document) {
      // The $ is now locally scoped

      // The rest of your code goes here!

  }(window.jQuery, window, document));
  // The global jQuery object is passed as a parameter
```

[Check here for references](http://gregfranko.com/blog/jquery-best-practices/)

Comment: This doesn't address the issue. Your solution is to provide `jQuery` as an argument to the IIFE yet that will simply cause the same error as the `<script>` tag referencing jQuery has not been loaded before the IIFE is defined.

Comment: You can see in my answer that i have clearly mentioned that he should have a reference to his JQUERY library .

Comment: Again, the OP *does* have a reference to jQuery. It's in the wrong place. That is the problem you've missed.